# VB.Net Sublime Text 2 Build Error

Tags: vb.net, msbuild

I am trying to find a good build system or fix a possible error with my current build system. Whenever I run the following code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Module EmployeeBonus2
   Sub Main
  ' Declare and initialize variables here
      Dim numOne as Integer = 10
      System.Console.WriteLine(10)
      System.Console.Read()
   End Sub
End Module
```

I get the following error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

Is there anyway to fix this? I am using the MSBuild package to attempt to build this in Sublime Text 2. Its a .VB file, so should I make my own build system and if so, how?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by 'Run the following code'?  VB.Net must be compiled into an executable before you can 'run' it.  And the normal way to compile VB.Net is to use MSBuild.  But MSBuild requires a .vbproj file to describe all the code files (and possibly other resources) that will get compiled into the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Visual Studio Community edition (it is free) then create a VB.Net project.

You can get it here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

Once you have the project structure and files created, you can use Sublime Text to edit the .vb files and use MSBuild from the command line to compile the project.

The code file(s) will end in .vb and the project file will end in .vbproj.

Once you have Visual Studio installed it will probably be easier to just edit and compile your code within Visual Studio.  Visual Studio also gives you a debugger.

Use the 'F5' function key to compile and run your code from Visual Studio.